# ng-submit with focus out event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-submit

In angularjs i have created a form on page ... when i enter text in input and press enter then ng-submit method is called , is there any method to call method on focus out Event.

Fiddle Code::
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lyz6z/

```
 <form ng-submit="submit(user.name,user.selectedOption)" class="data-dz-tag" >
      <br/><input type="text" placeholder="Caption" ng-model="user.name" name="text" style="width:125px" /><br/>
     <select ng-model="user.selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in options">{{option.name}}
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes you can do so but it would not be a recommonded behavior of your application. You should avoid this practice as user will be confused by this

Comment: Your jsfiddle is broken.

Comment: To do so, you can just bind ng-blur event for your text box and trigger submit(user.name,user.selectedOption) on that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by Adding ng-blur .

```
 <form ng-submit="submit(user.name,user.selectedOption)" class="data-dz-tag" >
<select ng-model="user.selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in options">
    {{option.name}}
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Caption" ng-model="user.name" name="text" style="width:125px" ng-blur="submit(user)"/>
<br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Good :) let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I did this too, but now I have the problem of submit being called twice, once on enter press and once after when user blurs the textfield. Any advice?